# Running celeryd_multi as a daemon

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celeryd

I'm using celery 3.0.11 and djcelery 3.0.11 with python 2.7 and django 1.3.4.
I'm trying to run celeryd as a daemon and I've followed instructions from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html

When I run the workers using celeryd as described in the link with a python (non-django) configuration, the daemon comes up.

When I run the workers using `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info` to test the workers, they come up fine and start to consume messages.

But when I run celeryd with a django configuration i.e. using `manage.py celeryd_multi`, I just get a message that says

```
> Starting nodes...
    > <node_name>.<user_name>: OK
```

But I don't see any daemon running and my messages obviously don't get consumed. There is an empty log file (the one that's configured in the celeryd config file).
I've tried this with a very basic django project as well and I get the same result.

I'm wondering if I'm missing any basic configuration piece. Since I don't get any errors and I don't have any logs, I'm stuck. Running it with sh-x doesn't show anything special either.
Has anyone experienced this before or does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try?

Thanks,

Comment: For now I've switched to using supervisord instead of celeryd and I have no issues running multiple workers. But I'd be really interested to know why celeryd_multi wouldn't work because I'm sure it did work a few weeks ago and How reliable is celeryd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've switched to using supervisord instead of celeryd and I have no issues running multiple workers.